# How do I change the color of individual page titles in WordPress?

Tags: theme-development, css, html

I am looking for custom CSS to add to my WordPress website to change the color of individual page titles. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: By just adding CSS and hard-coding post numbers in the CSS, or do you want this to be configurable per-post in the admin site?

Comment: Could you give an example of custom CSS for the title/h1 tag? this is what I tried but it didn't work:  h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

Answer (score 0):

Hide the default page title in the template and use a Gutenberg heading block instead. It should have a color control in the sidebar.

```css
.page .entry-header {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, unfortunately I won't be bale to use the Gutenberg editor, It has to be done with custom css.

Comment: On the most basic level, you can do this with the individual page ID's. If you inspect the page you'll see that the body tag has a few classes automatically added. Most themes will add something like .page-id-5 for a page with an ID of 5. Usually the home page and front page will also have .home or .blog respectively. 


Example:

`.page-id-5 .entry-title {color: #fff;}`